# Bathroom vents leaking

Tags: electrical

**Just wondering if people can shed light on my bathroom ventilation?**

I have 2 and one is the fan and just unsure what the other is. Both appear to have plastic trunking behind it.

My issue is in my loft the water is pooling in this trunking and leaking onto bathroom ceiling. I am hoping

Comment: Pictures would help

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.